# Getting the current url page ref scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to add the current url of the scraped page on my script. But for some reason I can't select this :

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.cdiscount.com/sante-mieux-vivre/hygiene-beaute-parapharmacie-bio/v-16516-16516.html" />
```

It is nested into the `head`.

I tried `response.xpath("//head/link[@rel='canonical']@href").extract()`

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the url of the current response. You can just use `response.url`

Comment: Thank you for the tip !!

Answer (score 2):

If you really need the canonical URL, this should work:

```
response.xpath("//link[@rel='canonical']/@href").get()
```

Your expression was missing `/` before `@href`.

You could also use CSS:

```
response.css("link[rel='canonical']::attr(href)").get()
```

If you don't care about the canonical URL, then you can follow @Yall's suggestion above.